# Is Mongoose Populate Smart?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose populate to populate users for a related action. Most of my actions share the same user. Is mongoose smart enough to fetch the user only once or does it perform an unintelligent join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will just fetch the referenced user once; in fact it will fetch all referenced users in a *single* query using `_id: {$in: [...ids...]}`.

You can confirm this by enabling debug output to the console via a call in your startup code so that you can see what queries Mongoose is performing:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```